# Create table with with clause in Hana

Tags: sql, hana

I want to create a table using with clause:

For example :

```
with cte as
(SELECT B.STEUC "HSN",
        CASE WHEN A.FORMAT_CD='520' THEN '2' ELSE A.FORMAT_CD END FORMAT_CD,
        CASE WHEN A.FORMAT_CD='520' THEN 'DIGITAL' ELSE A.FORMAT_DESC END FORMAT_DESC,
        A.ARTICLE,
        A.REGION "STATE",
        SUM(CASE WHEN BWART IN ('702','704','708','711','713','715','717','551','553','555','903','909','951','Z09') THEN DMBTR ELSE 0 END) - 
        SUM(CASE WHEN BWART IN ('701','703','707','712','714','716','718','552','554',' 556','904','910','952','Z10') THEN DMBTR ELSE 0 END) "LOSS_VALUE"
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."RRA.DnL/CV_STOCK_MOVEMENT" A INNER JOIN "P22"."MARA" B ON A.ARTICLE=B.MATNR 
WHERE posting_date BETWEEN '20181101' AND '20181130' AND
      BWART IN ('702','704',' 708',' 711','713','715','717','701','703','707','712','714','716','718','551',
      '552','553','554','555','556','903','904','909','910','951','952','Z09','Z10') AND
      A.COMPANY_CODE='9008' AND
      A.LEVEL2 NOT IN ('10','99') AND
      A.LEVEL5 NOT IN ('140601010') AND
      A.FORMAT_CD NOT IN ('51','56','62','509')
GROUP BY B.STEUC,A.ARTICLE,A.REGION,A.COMPANY_CODE,A.FORMAT_CD,
        A.FORMAT_DESC)
SELECT A.HSN,
       A.STATE,
       A.FORMAT_CD,
       A.FORMAT_DESC,
       A.ARTICLE,
       A.LOSS_ART,
       B.LOSS
FROM (
SELECT A.HSN,
          A.STATE,
       A.FORMAT_CD,
       A.FORMAT_DESC,
       A.ARTICLE,
       A.LOSS LOSS_ART,
       SUM(A.LOSS) OVER (PARTITION BY A.HSN,A.STATE,A.FORMAT_CD ORDER BY  LOSS DESC) LOSS   
FROM (SELECT A.HSN,A.STATE,A.FORMAT_CD,A.FORMAT_DESC,A.ARTICLE,SUM(LOSS_VALUE) LOSS FROM 
--"RR_ANALYST"."REETIKA_LOSS_DATA_1" 
cte A 
INNER JOIN P22.MARA B ON A.ARTICLE=B.MATNR
      WHERE B.ATTYP<>'11'
      GROUP BY A.HSN,A.STATE,A.FORMAT_CD,A.FORMAT_DESC,A.ARTICLE 
      HAVING SUM(LOSS_VALUE)>0 ) A
      ) A ,
      (SELECT A.HSN,A.STATE,A.FORMAT_CD,SUM(LOSS_VALUE) LOSS FROM 
      cte  A 
      group by A.HSN,A.STATE,A.FORMAT_CD HAVING SUM(LOSS_VALUE)>0) B
  WHERE A.HSN=B.HSN AND
        A.STATE=B.STATE AND
        A.FORMAT_CD=B.FORMAT_CD AND
        A.LOSS<=B.LOSS*1
```

Which i guess is not supported in Hana.

What can be an alternative to the same ? 
Does hana support spooling like oracle ?

I know i can export the result set and then create a table accordingly.

But is there any way to achieve and create the table dynamically ?

Comment: I updated the question with my original query. 
Also, by basic requirement is to create a table with with clause.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is the *oldfashioned* way - an inline view.

```
CREATE column TABLE t AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT 1 as some_value  --> this is your WITH factoring clause
        FROM dummy
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 
        FROM dummy
      );
```

Comment: This is just a demo query. My requirement has a different query which has a lot of records. I've optimised it using a with clause and need to create the table with the same.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The whole CTE can be used as an inline view. What you call "optimized" depends on what optimizer thinks about it, not the way you wrote so that it looks pretty. I'm not saying that you did anything wrong - just that I hope that you made sure that it really is *optimized*.